# How to find the last cell in a column which is supposed to be blank but has spaces?

Tags: vba, excel

So I have data with around 20,000 records. I want to set the range such that only data from Row 2 to 20,000 is checked in column A. However, cell 20,001 isn't blank, it could contain spaces as well. 
(This data is imported prior to validation, so I cannot alter it)

When I use .End(xlUp) it ends up checking till some 50,000th row.

Any Help?

Sample:

Column A

A

B

(2 spaces inserted)

---

### I want to check for cells only till B(including it)

Update: 
Managed to return the last required cell to the main sub

```
Private Sub last()
Dim rngX As Range

Set rngX = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").EntireColumn.Find("  ", lookat:=xlPart)

    If Not rngX Is Nothing Then
       /* return value 
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Long ago in 2011 @Tim Williams suggested to find Last not empty cell in row; ~Worksheets("your sheet").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Select~ . A further confirmation can be obtained by ISEMPTY Function. The ISEMPTY function returns a Boolean value that indicates whether a single cell is empty: True if empty, False if not. The cell must truly be empty for the function to return True. Even if it has a space that you cannot see, Excel does not consider the cell to be empty:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GD pnuts,

If you want to use VBA, you could contemplate checking for [space] character ? assuming the cell contains only spaces (or only one for that matter)

Something like:

```
Dim r as range
set r = range("B")

For each c in r.rows

    if instr(1, c.value,chr(32)) > 0 then
    'do something
    end if

next
```

You could function a check of all characters in cell.value string to validate that they are only spaces ?

Does that help ?

Comment: Thanks, yeah. I used a find function in the column for multiple spaces: "  " and then returned that cell address from the function to the main sub.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will have to test each cell individually. To make the number of cells to check smaller, and to speed things up, I would first read the column to check into a Variant array, and then check that from bottom to top.  I the spaces are truly a `space`, the test below will work.  If the space is a `NBSP`, or a combination, then you will have to revise the check to ensure that is the only thing present.

e.g: to check column A:

```
Option Explicit
Sub foo()
    Dim R As Range
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim V As Variant
    Dim I As Long

Set WS = Worksheets("sheet2")
With WS
    V = .Range("a1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    For I = UBound(V) To LBound(V) Step -1

        'Revise this check line as needed
        If Len(Trim(V(I, 1))) > 0 Then Exit For
    Next I
    Set R = .Cells(I, 1)
End With

Debug.Print R.Address

End Sub
```

You might want to add some error checking in case all of the cells are empty.